# What is the probability that exactly 2 out of the 7 dealt cards will be face cards?

Tags: probability

If 7 cards are dealt from an ordinary pack of 52 playing cards, what is the probability that exactly 2 of them will be face cards? A face card is either a jack, a queen or a king. This seems relatively simple, but I couldn’t solve it. Any ideas?

Comment: Were you able to understand? Or are there still doubts?

Comment: Yes, thanks, permutations and combinations isn’t one of my strongest subjects though.

Comment: "You know how you get to Carnegie Hall, don't you? Practice!" - Lt. Aldo Raine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need $2$ face cards in a $7$ card draw. What are the number of ways you can do this?

First you must have $2$ face cards in your hand:

$$\text{No. of ways of picking 2 face cards}= \binom{12}{2}$$

Now the other 5 cards must come from non-face cards:

$$\text{No. of ways of picking 5 non-face cards }= \binom{40}{5}$$

Now the total no. of ways with which you can pick $7$ cards such that exactly $2$ of them are face cards is:

$$\binom{12}{2} \times \binom{40}{5}$$

Right?

Now you need the probability of the event where you pick $7$ cards with exactly $2$ face cards in it.

What are the total no. of ways with which you can pick $7$ cards?

$$\binom{52}{7}$$

Now since all the combinations of $7$ card hands are equally likely, the required probability is simply:

$$\frac{\binom{12}{2} \times \binom{40}{5}}{\binom{52}{7}}$$

Cheers!